# Displaylink monitor keeps disconnecting when I bump into my desk

Tags: macos, display, mac-mini

I have a 3 monitor setup that uses DisplayLink for the 3th screen. The 3th monitor disconnects 1-10 times a day. It seems like it is caused by a minor difference in power; when I plug in my phone charger next to the Mac / docking station power, the connection is lost. Most of the times, just bumping into my desk is enough to disconnect the monitor (even the act of just standing up does the trick).

After disconnecting, the DisplayLink manager says: `No DisplayLink-enabled display detected` To reconnect it, I have to repeatedly unplug the DisplayLink docking station, and restart DisplayLink manager, until the monitor is detected again. Sometimes the monitor is detected immediately, sometimes it takes a while.

I'm not quite sure whether this problem is caused by power fluctuations, bad connection, or missing/bad config. All I know is that I am looking for a way to solve this issue, every suggestion is welcome;

- power hardware to prevent power fluctuations,
- a better docking station,
- a bash script that re-establishes the connection without the need to unplug hardware,

My setup is:

- Mac mini M1 2020
- Dell DisplayLink d3100
- 3x Dell S2721HN

Comment: How precisely is this third display physically connected to the mini?

Answer (score 0):

Buy a can of contact cleaner*.
Power everything down & disconnect from the mains. Spray each plug/socket liberally. Insert/remove every pairing a dozen or so times as it's drying, then leave to fully dry for an hour, or overnight [it evaporates fast except for really tucked-away areas, but better safe than sorry, it can be condictive when still wet.] Re-assemble & re-test.

After that, if it still does it, you can think about checking/swapping/replacing cables.

*Don't get the cheapest you can find. You get what you pay for. Cheap ones will either take too long to dry, leave residue, rot plastic [or all three]. I use this one, but it's not the only decent one available - https://wd40.co.uk/product/fast-drying-contact-cleaner/ - not to be confused with the lubricant you spray on cars [*don't use that*], just the same manufacturer.